# android studio running error E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7 Process

Tags: android

I am a super beginner of android studio.
I downloaded a source code in github and encountered error running it.
My android version is 3.2 and 9.0 pie.

https://github.com/pangguoming/android-camera-color-picker

The error is like below. Bold lines are errors.

---

10/24 09:07:41: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.pangguoming.whatcolor/com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 16649 on device sm_g950n-ce031713a52c54930c
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from the current namespace instead.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/yanzi: Camera open....
I/yanzi: Camera open over....
I/DisplayUtil: Screen---Width = 1080 Height = 2009 densityDpi = 480

> ***E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
>       Process: com.pangguoming.whatcolor, PID: 16649
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.SurfaceHolder
>   com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraSurfaceView.getSurfaceHolder()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraActivity.cameraHasOpened(CameraActivity.java:77)
>           at com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraInterface.doOpenCamera(CameraInterface.java:51)
>           at com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraActivity$1.run(CameraActivity.java:36)***
>   I/DisplayUtil: Screen---Width = 1080 Height = 2009 densityDpi = 480
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
>   D/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: setView =
>   DecorView@19a5f5f[CameraActivity] TM=true MM=false
>   D/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   D/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,2009] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0}
>   changed=false
>   ***E/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: Surface is not valid.*** D/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][1080,2009] new=[0,0][1080,2009] result=0x1
>   surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
>   D/ViewRootImpl@1927bfe[CameraActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   D/InputEventReceiver: channel 'b2fa8d0
>   com.pangguoming.whatcolor/com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraActivity
>   (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
>       channel 'b2fa8d0 com.pangguoming.whatcolor/com.pangguoming.whatcolor.CameraActivity
>   (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver. Application terminated.

---

How can I fix it? Help me!

Comment: Please don't just link to a project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: This is not a well-formatted question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread openThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CameraInterface.getInstance().doOpenCamera(CameraActivity.this);
        }
    };
    openThread.start();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    initUI();
    initViewParams();

    shutterBtn.setOnClickListener(new BtnListeners());
}
```

This code is problematic. It runs `doOpenCamera()` before running `initUI()`. `doOpenCamera()` takes an instance of `CamOpenOverCallback` as an argument, which the `CameraActivity` implements.

When `doOpenCamera()` completes, it calls `cameraHasOpened()` on the `CamOpenOverCallback` instance it was passed. However, the code in `cameraHasOpened()` makes a call on the global `surfaceView` variable, and `surfaceView` is initialized under `initUI()`.

Since `doOpenCamera()` is performed on a separate Thread (I'm honestly not sure why, since one of the reasons for the use of a callback is to avoid using Threads), it's possible that `initUI()` will complete before `doOpenCamera()` does, however it's not guaranteed.

`cameraHasOpened()` may be invoked *before* `initUI()`, meaning `surfaceView` is null at that point, leading to your NPE.

The code in that sample project seems kind of sloppy to be honest, and I wouldn't recommend using it. If you need a quick fix, though, some reordering will work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    initUI();
    initViewParams();

    shutterBtn.setOnClickListener(new BtnListeners());

    Thread openThread = new Thread(){ //make the Thread invocation the LAST thing in onCreate()
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CameraInterface.getInstance().doOpenCamera(CameraActivity.this);
        }
    };
    openThread.start();
}
```

To really fix this issue, though, the Thread itself should be moved to CameraInterface.

Currently, `doOpenCamera()` looks like this:

```
public void doOpenCamera(CamOpenOverCallback callback){
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera open....");
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera open over....");
    callback.cameraHasOpened();
}
```

It should look like this:

```
public void doOpenCamera(CamOpenOverCallback callback) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera open....");
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera open over....");
            callback.cameraHasOpened();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And `onCreate()` in CameraActivity should look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    initUI();
    initViewParams();

    shutterBtn.setOnClickListener(new BtnListeners());

    CameraInterface.getInstance().doOpenCamera(CameraActivity.this); //remove the wrapped Thread
}
```

---

Keep in mind that this project uses the deprecated Camera API. Any project targeting devices running Lollipop (API 21) or later should be using the Camera2 API, while still implementing the deprecated Camera API to provide compatibility to older devices.